# How to add form fields dynamically in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to add form fields dynamically.

I also want that on click the durationprice add dynamically and also a button to add dynamically full plan.

```
{ plan: [ { planname: "", description: "", cuisine: "", durationprice: [{duration: "",maximumduration: "", price: ""}]}]}
```

```js
import React, {
  Component,
  useState
} from "react";
import DurationPrice from "./DurationandPrice";
import Rules from "./Rules";

const TOKEN = 'hello';
export function PlanForm() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{
    planName: "",
    description: "",
    cuisine: "",
  }, ]);

  const handleChnage = (e, index) => {
    const {
      name,
      value
    } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };
  const handleInput = () => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.push({
      planName: "",
      description: "",
      cuisine: ""
    });
    setInputList(list);
    // setInputList([...inputList,{firstName:'',lastName:''}]);
  };
  const handleRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

  };
  const handleSave = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('button clicked');
    fetch(`https://cosynest-api.herokuapp.com/api/plans/create`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'duration': inputList.duration,
          'maximumDuration': inputList.maximumDuration,
          'price': inputList.price
        }),
        headers: new Headers({
          Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(console.log(inputList))
      .then(localStorage.setItem('Token-CreateShop', TOKEN))
      .catch(console.log('error'))

  }
  // debugger;
  return ( <
    div className = "plan-form" > {
      inputList.map((item, i) => {
        return ( <
          form key = {
            i
          }
          onSubmit = {
            handleSubmit
          } >
          <
          input type = "text"
          name = "planName"
          className = "mr-10 input "
          placeholder = "Plan Name"
          value = {
            item.planName
          }
          onChange = {
            (e) => handleChnage(e, i)
          }
          /> <
          input type = "text"
          name = "description"
          className = "mr-10 input "
          placeholder = "Description"
          value = {
            item.description
          }
          onChange = {
            (e) => handleChnage(e, i)
          }
          /> <
          input type = "cuisine"
          onChange = {
            (e) => handleChnage(e, i)
          }
          value = {
            item.cuisine
          }
          className = "mr-10 input "
          name = "cuisine"
          placeholder = "Cuisine" /
          >

          <
          h2 > Duration and Price < /h2> <
          DurationPrice / >
          <
          br / >
          <
          div > {
            inputList.length - 1 === i && ( <
              button type = "button"
              onClick = {
                handleInput
              }
              className = "mr-10 btn"
              value = "Add Plan" >
              Add Plan <
              /button>
            )
          } {
            inputList.length !== 1 && ( <
              button onClick = {
                () => handleRemove(i)
              }
              className = "mr-10 btn-red"
              value = "Remove Plan" >
              Remove <
              /button>
            )
          } <
          /div>

          <
          /form>
        );
      })
    } <
    button onClick = {
      handleSave
    }
    className = "btn-pink btn "
    type = "submit" > Save PLANS < /button> {
      /* <pre>
                          {JSON.stringify(inputList,null,3)}
                      </pre> */
    } <
    /div>
  );
}

export default PlanForm;
```

Comment: have you written anything?

Comment: yes but that not working . i have made 2 components for both . but i want to add only one component

Comment: you should add the code too. Whenever you're asking a question, it's better to know where you're at, right.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one state that will have all the `formData` states inside it and for the input elements you can use `map` to render
lets say you have to create form for these fields

```
let formElements = [{
    label: "Name", // this is label
    key: 'name' // this is unique key to be used as state name 
}, {
    label: "Phone number",
    key: 'phone'
}, {
    label: "House",
    key: 'house'
}, {
    label: "City",
    key: 'city'
}, {
    label: "State",
    key: 'state'
}, {
    label: "Country",
    key: 'country'
}]
```

now you can create your component from this element something like this

```
export default function App() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({} as any);

    const handleChange = (value: string, key: string) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, ...{ [key]: value } });
    }

    const submit = () => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(formData))
    }

    return (
        <form>
            Form goes here
            {formElements.map(formElement => {
                return <div>
                    {formElement.label}
                    <input value={formData[formElement.key]}
                        onChange={(e) => { handleChange(e.target.value, formElement.key) }} />
                </div>
            })}
            <button onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); submit() }}>submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Now whenever you want to update the form fields just update your `formElements` Array.

in your case you can store formElements in state and update that like this

```
  const [formElement,setFormElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setFormElements(formElement)
  },[]);

// update your state with new element like this on button click
  const updateFormElememt = (newElement)=>{
    setFormElements([...formElements,...newElement])
  }
```